# Check on leaflet map for markers with specific icon

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, marker

I want to check if there is a marker on the map with a "markerIconActive" icon.

I think the best would be to loop through all markers and check if there is one with a "markerIconActive" icon and if there's one to change it to "markerIconVisited". But how?

I use a marker clusterer so i can't just edit the DOM Elements Class to change the appearence of the marker.

Marker Icons:

```
var markerIconActive = L.divIcon({
        className: 'marker--state--active',
        html: "15",
        iconAnchor: [20, 20]
});
var markerIconVisited = L.divIcon({
        className: 'marker--state--visited',
        html: "15",
        iconAnchor: [20, 20]
});
```

I want to do it in vanilla Javascript.

Comment: No, i want to check all markers for markers with specific icon. To change them is the second step (and allready answered in the thread you linked).

Comment: Alright. removed.